# How to solve this jvm runtime exception?

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, encoding, jvm

Whenever I try to run the following code in fishy.kt (Kotlin):

```
val paddingChar = '='
val lookupTable = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567"
fun base32Decode(encodedString: String): ByteArray {
    // Remove whitespace and padding characters
    val encodedStringCleaned = encodedString.replace(" ", "").replace(paddingChar.toString(), "")
    // Prepare a map for reverse lookup
    val reverseLookupTable = lookupTable.withIndex().associateBy({ it.value }, { it.index })
    // Convert Base32 string to binary
    val binaryString = encodedStringCleaned.flatMap { reverseLookupTable[it]?.toString(2)?.padStart(5, '0') ?: error("Invalid Base32 character") }
        .joinToString("")
    // Add trailing zeros if necessary
    val remainder = binaryString.length % 8
    val paddedBinaryString = if (remainder != 0) binaryString.padEnd(binaryString.length + 8 - remainder, '0') else binaryString
    // Convert binary to bytes
    val bytes = paddedBinaryString.chunked(8)
        .map { it.toInt(2).toByte() }
        .toByteArray()
    return bytes
}
// Example usage
val encodedString = "MZXW6==="
val decodedData = base32Decode(encodedString)
println(decodedData.contentToString())
```

I get the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at FishKtyour text.base32Decode(fish.kt)
        at FishKt.main(fish.kt:3)
        at FishKt.main(fish.kt)
```

Any solutions for this?

I am trying to decode a base32 string in Kotlin, but as there is no inbuilt base32 decoder, I tried to write my own but still got this error.

Comment: How are you running your program and how is it organized? Looks like something is missing on your classpath

Comment: I am running program using kotlinc and java

Comment: You either need to run it with `kotlin`, or you need to add the Kotlin runtime jars to your classpath when running with `java`.